# I'm trying to find the manufacturer and age of French Patio Doors

Tags: windows

grateful for any advise anyone can give me.
I'm trying to find the manufacturer and age of French Patio Doors installed before we bought the house.

Inside frame
RHEN12608SIIAG353203903071206503820042029

Inside other frame 
RHEN12608SIIAG35314350307052--8550022074

Inside glass
RAVENSBY KM25420 BSEN1279-2

Photos of doors attached [image][image]

Comment: In what country?

Comment: If you're lucky, there are marks indicating that the glass is tempered... sometimes these include a year. Look to the corners of the glass, or to the separators.

Comment: Scotland, United Kingdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual glass was made by Ravensby Glass Co. And the company that made the doors is called Rehau. They mold(ed) plastic frames anyway.

Here's a link to their [home page](http://www.rehauhome.com/default.aspx): http://www.rehauhome.com/default.aspx

I think that you'll need to contact them to figure out the age... but sometimes the date of manufacturing is part of the numbers... like 12608 might mean 12/6/08. In Europe that would be June 12, 2008... in USA, it's December 6, 2008... but then again, sometimes the number refers to the day that the design was created- not the actual door, and then of course the number might be meaningless- just a fingerprint.